# schemagen NullpointerException

Tags: nullpointerexception, schemagen

**Java class:**

```
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "user", propOrder = {
            "id",
            "name"  })
    public class User {
        @XmlAttribute(required=true)
        private long id;
        @XmlAttribute(required=true)
            private String name;
        public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + "]";
    }
 }
```

- **JDK version** : 1.6.0_31
- **Exception Stack Trace** schemagen User.java

  ```
  C:\anirban\work_eclipse_juno\RestfulWSDemo\src\com\domain>schemagen User.java
  An exception has occurred in apt (1.6.0_31). Please file a bug at the Java Devel
  oper Connection (http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport)  after checking the Bug
  Parade for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your
   report.  Thank you.
  java.lang.NullPointerException
          at com.sun.tools.apt.main.CommandLine.parse(CommandLine.java:42)
          at com.sun.tools.apt.main.Main.compile(Main.java:775)
          at com.sun.tools.apt.Main.processing(Main.java:95)
          at com.sun.tools.apt.Main.process(Main.java:85)
          at com.sun.tools.apt.Main.process(Main.java:67)
          at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
          at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
  java:39)
          at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
  sorImpl.java:25)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
          at com.sun.tools.internal.jxc.SchemaGenerator$Runner.main(SchemaGenerato
  r.java:215)
          at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
          at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
  java:39)
          at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
  sorImpl.java:25)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
          at com.sun.tools.internal.jxc.SchemaGenerator.run(SchemaGenerator.java:1
  53)
          at com.sun.tools.internal.jxc.SchemaGenerator.run(SchemaGenerator.java:6
  3)
          at com.sun.tools.internal.jxc.SchemaGenerator.main(SchemaGenerator.java:
  55)
  ```

  Can anyone please help me out here?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the classpath.
schemagen -cp "%java_home%\lib\tools.jar" User.java